# Dual Booting Windows and ubuntu, Ubuntu won't load. Grub help

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, wubi

I installed Ubuntu using Wubi. It has been working fine for the past 5 months, but I tried to boot it recently and instead of loading Ubuntu I get the Grub terminal. What commands do I need to enter so I can load/boot Ubuntu?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending of the Grub version you have installed. (depending of Ubuntu Version).
Let s suppose that you have GRUB2 installed. you are in the GRUB2 shell.
Let s suppose that you see something like : grub:sh>
Then GRUB2 menu file may be corrupted.

Write down each of the following commands on a single line after the prompt  grub:sh> :

```
search -f --set=Root /boot/grub/core.img
set root=(${Root})
probe -u (${Root}) --set=UUID
linux /vmlinuz root=UUID=${UUID} ro
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

After this, Ubuntu will load. To regenerate the GRUB 2 menu, run the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Hope this helps.
Do not hesitate to provide more details , if needed.